# javascript dropdown menu gets hidden by acrobat reader

Tags: drop-down-menu, z-index

my menu was implemented in javascript as dropdown menu and the area below is an iframe where acrobat reader would display a PDF document. for some reason, my dropdown menu always goes behind the acrobat reader. Is it possible to make the reader go behind the dropdown?
Thanks.

Comment: Use css to move the dropdown above in the z axis (`z-index:12345;`) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: I have tried z-index but it is of no use. in IE 8.